# Proof that $ \operatorname{det}\left(A^{-1}-\frac{1}{\lambda} I\right)=0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Here is my problem: $$\\$$
Let $ A $ is the reversible matrix, $ \lambda \in R$ satisfy $\operatorname{det}(A-\lambda I)=0 $
where I is the identity matrix.
Proof that:
$$
\operatorname{det}\left(A^{-1}-\frac{1}{\lambda} I\right)=0
$$
Thank you for your help.

Comment: How familiar are you with eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hint:*

- $\det B = 0 \iff $ $B$ is singular $\iff Bv=0$ for some $v\ne0$
- $Av = \lambda v \implies \frac{1}{\lambda} v = A^{-1}v$

Comment: Very nice hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ is a non-zero eigen value of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ exist, then
$$\det|A-\lambda I|=0 \implies \det|A(I-\lambda A^{-1}) \implies \det|A^{-1}|\det|I-\lambda A^{-1}|=0$$ $$ \implies \det|A^{-1}-\frac{I}{\lambda}|=0$$

Comment: Great proof. Thank you very much.

Comment: No need to mention eigenvalues.